# Liquid physics game

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I have to develop a game which will have water inside a bucket. The user can make the water move around the bucket by shaking the device. There will be light weight rings and mud inside the bucket settled at the bottom of the bucket. User can pump in air from the bottom of the bucket, and the rings and the mud will react to the air pressure applied from the bottom, as in a normal world.

Can I achieve this using `cocos2d-box2d`? Or shall I use a different game engine?

Can you please share an url for the sample applications or tutorials related to this topic?

Comment: Please give the reason for the down vote so that next time I improve.

Comment: go for unity it will make ur life much easier

Comment: @amar - Can liquid physics be integrated the way I want using unity?

Comment: As far as i understand you want to make a game similar to wateh game we used to play in childhood pressing button will throw things up and we have to guide it to a basket.Yes you can do it in unity its for gaming

Comment: @amar - Exactly. Alright. I will have to do a little R&D on that as unity is new for me. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/25494 it may help you

Comment: Unity's learning curve if little large

Comment: Liquid physics is all about the physics engine. Box2D is alright for that, and so are most other physics engines. The hard part will definitely not be about picking the right engine, it'll be implementing the fluid physics.

Comment: Go for physics engine

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using box2d. For more information check this links:

```
http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/buoyancy
http://www.sideroller.com/wck/?f=6
http://files.slembcke.net/temp/Waves1D.tgz
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/05/16/simulating-mudslime-with-box2d-bitmaps-and-filters/
```